# How to split data into rows

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I want to split one data columns by ";" and add it into rows. I believe in tableau this is called pivoting. But it wont work for me.

I have no issues splitting the data by delimiter, but it add's as column and not row. I don't get the option of pivoting afterwards, it could be due its a 'caulculated' field?

[image]

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is not so easy, but let's get through this:

This is my sample data:

[image]

ID is still a number, I convert it to a *dimension* later.

Now, instead of creating a calculated field you do a custom split on your data, just like shown below. In the window that opens up you insert your seperator, which is "`;`" and the number of columns you need, which seems to be 10 in your case. I choose 3.

[image]

Then you create a table like this one:

[image]

and go on to create a crosstable like this:

[image]

then you klick on `data` and then `paste`. You'll now get a crosstable in a new sheet.
Now proceed by right-clicking on the newly created data source,

[image]

select the three `Country-Split`-columns, choose one to click on the arrow and click `pivot`. No you can delete the `Country-Split`-columns and you get this:

[image]

I think this might be what you want.